# multiple pattern match in a file perl

Tags: perl

1. I have an hash which contains ~15000 keys:

   ```
   say %hash =(key1=>[x,yz],key2=>[o,p,e] ,key3......till keys 15000)
   ```
2. I have a file (100 MB)

In that file the hash's keys are repeated in many lines, so my file might contain

```
key1 there is adog
key2 there is cattt
key1 there is man
key3 there is elephant
key2 etc...............
```

Now what I want is

```
foreach my $key (keys %hash)
{
    open (IN,$file) or die ;
    while ($input=<IN>){
        ($animal)=$input=~/$key.*?there is (.*?)/I;
        #I want to match the last occurrence of the pattern I.e key1 there is **man**
    }
    push @array,$animal;
}
```

As you see this is working fine but the script is opening the file multiple times (15000) times for each key so it's taking lot's of time.

How I can optimize the code so that it will take comparatively less time

I used

```
my $stg=`grep -w $key /path/to/file |tail -1`;
```

but still the grep command will be executed 15000 times which is also taking lots of time.

My question is how I can execute this faster.

Answer (score 1):

As you read each line, simply overwrite the key value with the value in the current line.  That's a single pass through your file.

```
my %refs;
open my $IN '<', $file or die;
while ($input = <$IN>)
{
    my($key, $animal) = $input=~/^(^(\s+).*?there is (.*?)/I;
    $refs{$key} = $animal;
}
```

Now `%refs` contains the animal name for the last entry for each key:

```
foreach my $key (%refs)
{
    print "$key = $refs{$key}\n";
}
```